# Not able to install any new fonts on macos 11

Tags: macos, font, font-book

I tried the normal way by downloading the font and installing via font book, and also through homebrew. In both cases, I can't see the font.

I ran the console app and listened for events while I tried to install and found these events:

> 02:09:37.695768-0500  kernel  Sandbox: FontValidator(1005) deny(1) file-read-metadata /Users/hassan
> error   02:09:37.817436-0500    kernel  Sandbox: FontValidator(1005) deny(1) mach-issue-extension target:/Users/hassan/Downloads/Fira_Code_v5.2/ttf/FiraCode-Bold.ttf class:com.apple.app-sandbox.read

It appears there's some permission issue. I found another person from 2016 with a similar issue and they suggested switching the permission of the font files to 755 (they install to ~/Library/Fonts), but this didn't change anything.

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about your method? What did you use to download the fonts? Was the download successful? Can you supply a URL? What exactly happened, or did not happen, when you used Font book? Have you tried moving the fonts to the user Library's Fonts folder?

Comment: Also, is this definitely "ANY" new fonts? Have you tried others from more than one source?

Comment: Where  can you "not see" the font?  In Font Book?  Or in some App?  Have you also tried just dragging the font file into Users/username/Library/Fonts?

Comment: Try deleting the files in `~/Library/Fonts` if they exist, and then installing the fonts again.